# getting "no module named jsonpickle" error in lamdbda when using xray SDK

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-xray

I am getting "No module named jsonpickle" when I use AWS Xray SDK for python in my lambda. When I traced where it was being used it was imported into in aws_xray_sdk/core/models/entity.py. Do I need to add jsonpickle manually to the SDK? though it sounded a bit counter intuitive i downloaded it but it needs numpy and a couple of other libraries to be imported. I am confused. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: if you installed it properly it should take care. jsonpickle is included as dependency in setup.py https://github.com/aws/aws-xray-sdk-python/blob/master/setup.py

Comment: Thanks for looking it up but mine is on a lambda, I didn't even install it. I downloaded it directly from github. Another new thing I noticed is, I am not getting it if I change the version of python from 2.7 to 3.6 in my lambda. The code doesn't run but it parses past the "from aws_xray_sdk.core import xray recorder" line without any issues.

Comment: If you use `pip install aws-xray-sdk` and follow the guide of zipping the lambda deployment package, jsonpickle should be present on lambda execution.